# Using Azure AD to authenticate users in a .net core application (Blazor)

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, blazor-server-side

im trying to use azure Ad to authenticate users to my web application. I have configured the app so it works with local host fine, communicated with azure AD and returns the web page once successfully authenticated. However, when i publish to the web it doesn't work and instead i get an error :

AADSTS50011: The reply url specified in the request does not match the reply urls configured

is there an additional step required when using a mydomain.azurewebsites.net?

ps. the redirect URL has been configured to return /signin-oidc as instructed as docs show.

Comment: The Redirect URI in your Azure App Registration should be configured with the full name: https://mydomain.azurewebsites.net/signin-microsoft

Comment: Have you added required `mydomain.azurewebsites.net` domain reply url in registered Azure AD application?

Comment: @user1672994 yes. added redirecturl with https://domain.azurewebsites.net/signin-oidc

Answer (score 0):

The Redirect URI in your Azure App Registration should be configured with the full name: https://mydomain.azurewebsites.net/signin-microsoft

This is how I have added my Authentication to my Web App:

```
        services.AddAuthentication()
            .AddOpenIdConnect("Azure AD / Microsoft", "Azure AD / Microsoft", options =>
            {
                //  https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration
                options.ClientId = Configuration["AzureApplication:ClientID"];
                options.ClientSecret = Configuration["AzureApplication:ClientSecret"];
                options.SignInScheme = "Identity.External";
                options.RemoteAuthenticationTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
                options.Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0/";
                //options.ResponseType = "code";
                
                // new in .NET Core 3.1
                options.UsePkce = false; // live does not support this yet

                options.Scope.Add("profile");
                options.Scope.Add("email");
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuer = false,
                    NameClaimType = "email",
                };
                options.CallbackPath = "/signin-microsoft";
                options.Prompt = "login"; // login, consent
            });
```

Comment: my Callbackpath in my json settings file is "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc" , so it is still /signin-microsoft or the one specified in my callbackPath? cheers

Comment: @smeca Im using /signin-microsoft for my site but i dont really know the difference. :)

Comment: is your site live or are you using localhost?

Comment: @smeca yes my site is live (but in beta).

Comment: this is making me pull my hair out. is your application using blazor? / .net core 3.1?

Comment: I'm using .Net Core 3.1 but not Blazor. I have updated my response with how my Authentication is configured. Maybe that can give you a clue whats wrong.